# NSPredicate and custom NSObject

Tags: ios, nspredicate

I have a custom NSObject which I need to filter. I have been trying to user NSPredicate to do this, but was unable to so far. Here is my object's structure:

```
@interface MyBigObject : NSObject 

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *firstAttribute;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *secondAttribute;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *featuresArray;

@end
```

The featuresArray contains other custom objects:

```
typedef enum {

FeatureExists = YES, //Default
FeatureDoesNotExist = NO,
FeatureNotAvailable

} FeatureValue;

@interface MySmallObject : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic) FeatureValue feature;

@end
```

I want to only return the objects containing a MySmallObject with a certain title and which has feature == FeatureExists.

I've tried something like (and other variations) but to no success:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(featuresArray, $object, $object.title CONTAINS[c] %@ AND $object.feature = %d).@count > 0)", @"Fenced", FeatureExists];

NSLog(@"predicate = %@", predicate);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, the format of your predicate is wrong. It should be `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(featuresArray, $object, $object.title CONTAINS[c] %@ AND $object.feature = %d).@count > 0", @"some string", FeatureExists];` where you check in your array if any object matches the requirements.

Comment: I used it like:  NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(featuresArray, $object, $object.title CONTAINS[c] %@ AND $object.feature = %@).@count > 0)", @"exampleTitle", FeatureExists]; but it keeps crashing with exc_bad_access

Comment: Exc_Bad_Access means you're accessing a deallocated object. Check your allocations with the Zombie Instrument in Instruments. You might also want to add an exceptions breakpoint to your project (breakpoints navigation in Xcode -> add (+ sign at the bottom left) -> exceptions breakpoint).

EDIT: I see the problem in the code. The feature property of your object is an enum, therefore an integer, not an object therefore in the predicate you should use %d, instead of %@. I fixed the predicate in my answer accordingly.

Comment: this gets thrown exactly on the line I mentioned.

Comment: I've edited comment and answer. I saw where the problem was. ;)

Comment: I've updated my answer to show you exactly how I do it. It still crashes, but with 'Unable to parse the format string "SUBQUERY(featuresArray, $object, $object.featureTitle CONTAINS[c] %@ AND $object.feature = %d).@count > 0)"'. And it does not reach the NSLog.

Comment: Just fixed it in the answer ;).

Comment: @Gianluca Thanks. I've already accepted your answer, but am curious how would I add a second object to the search?

Comment: Figured it out. Just add another subquery. Thanks